# Allow new users to hide their reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I consider this bullying. I am a new user. I have no reputation, which means I have no power to retaliate arbitrary or unwarranted downgrading. I asked a perfectly sensible question. Someone casually and apparently from their own ignorance downgraded it. I corrected them by linking them to the documentation explaining the point they were confused on. I then  asked them to reverse the downgrading. Nothing doing.

As I understand it, this means my question will not be seen or will be ignored by a large number of viewers. The person who did this can plainly see they have nothing to fear from me a new user. I believe this incentivizes people to causally and arbitrarily downgrade questions instead of doing the research they would normally do before risking a downgrade. Is there some reason the fact that I am a new user is exposed to such people? Could you provide a way to choose between showing and not showing our "reputation" instead of making it public?

Here is the relevant post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234087/detecting-when-flow-of-control-has-shifted-to-native-thread-in-java

Comment: Everybody gets downvoted from time to time. This has nothing to do with reputation. If the question is any good, they will be evened out by upvotes over time.

Comment: You'll find you get downvoted less if you take the time to learn how the site works, including its terminology and what sort of questions are welcome here. For example, it is not called "downgrading" and never has been. Furthermore, you have no evidence whatsoever that it was _that_ user who downvoted you, and [your question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/234087/17853) sits at -1 which isn't that bad. I'd say welcome and suck it up — certainly, calling this "bullying" is just childish attention-seeking.

Comment: Rather than assuming everyone who downvotes you is maliciously bullying you without any merit whatsoever, consider that there is some actual problem with your post, and fix it.  You'll be *far* better off if you do.  (And, incidentally, everyone else who reads your improved answer will be better off as well.)

Comment: Oh, and the fact that you'd even _consider_ "retaliating" on a downvote makes me rather concerned that you have any chance of a constructive future in our community.

Comment: Oh, and don't assume that just because someone comments on your post at around the same time that it gets a downvote that the commenter downvoted you.  They may well not have.

Comment: ...particularly when they go on to bother writing a good answer on it.

Comment: Seeing how you treated gnat on his answer, I wish there were a way I could elect not to see your posts at all instead of them being forcibly revealed to me.

Comment: Ok Servy what's wrong with the post? Nothing. To say people don't  retaliate online using whatever means at their disposal  is amusing, at best. Welcome to the real world and people who talk frankly about it. As far as terminologiess, actually, if you understood what i was trying to communicate then I've done what is required. Your tenderness about what words to use to describe things in the world is .. amusing. As far as "sucking it up" goes, no I don't think I  am required to be sucking anything up. Sucking it up is what we tell people to do we want to abuse.

Comment: I see no malice here at all. gnat asked what you meant by the term "native thread", you clarified that, and then *you* were the one to attack him in the comments on his answer. I doubt he was the one who downvoted you, he was the one who asked for clarification and then tried to help you with an answer. Instead, you bit his hand.

Comment: @user125027 Your post has all *sorts* of problems.  If you spent some time trying to either find out what they were, or even fixing them, instead of putting on blinders and assuming you couldn't possibly have done anything wrong, you'd have a better post, and it'd be much more likely to be received as such by the community.  To specifically discuss your post, you're asking for product reccomendations; that's offtopic on that site.  The question is very broad; too broad in my mind.  It's also not exactly clear what you mean (hence the clarifying questions).

Comment: As far as retaliation goes, voting needs to come based on content alone, not the person posting it, and we will warn and suspend users who target others with retaliatory downvotes. You can't take downvotes personally, as even high-reputation users get downvoted all the time when they post incorrect answers or low-quality content.

Comment: Servy, it is simply false that I am asking for "product recommendations". Please re-read the question and / or learn some Java before commenting on the content of the post. Best wishes.

Comment: Lol. One downvote turned into many, through sheer attitude.

Comment: @user125027 Well, if it's not, it reads as if it is, which is *still* a problem with the post that you can fix.  If your post is being misunderstood, then *that* is a problem.  Rather than blaming people for misunderstanding it, edit the post to use clearer language.

Comment: "It seems simple but I am unable to think of an enabling technology." That can easily be interpreted as a request for a product/resource recommendation. And I agree with the others in terms of your attitude being really inappropriate.

Comment: It only seems like a product recommendation if you don't understand the question in the first place. Technology != product. We can start there.

Comment: Pekka- thanks for admitting tot he premise of this question, however inadvertently you did that. People are voting their feelings- nothing to do with the actual merit of the question itself- and their ignorance.

Comment: Servy- no one can ask a  question  in such a way so that *people who do not understand the technology involved will not be confused*. To require that of questioners is absurd on the face of it. Have you googled "stackexchange sucks" lately? Because what people complain about is in  full display right here, right now both here and  in my other  post. What the financial beneficiaries of this site need to ask themselves is- are we going to let high usage trolls destroy the utility of this site  or are we going to take action against   users who have come to think (and act) of it as "theirs"?

Comment: Getting free programming help on a web site largely run by volunteers involves being somewhat civil. The financial beneficiaries of the place should be fine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YTrDT.png

Comment: What people complain about is people like you, acting like this.

Comment: Look, downgrading a question because you don't understand then trying to justify that downgrading retroactively by citing irrelevant  "facts" *you just read about* which, if they were contrextualized would immediately be understood as irrelevant, is not nice". Piling on to down vote a question- perhaps admins of this site can confirm that the trolls in this thread also downvoted my question in the other one..do ya think? doing that is specifically against the spirit and letter of SE. Complaining about same is NOT a form of trolling and neither is demanding to be free of such bullying tactics.

Comment: If you get one downvote, look if something's wrong with your question. If you don't see anything, ignore it;  a subsequent upvote will eventually fix things. But don't go "OMG HOW DARE THEY THEY MUST NOT UNDERSTAND JAVA"

Comment: In fact it would be great if anyone who trolled me in this thread and then downvoted my question would be banned for violating the rules of the site. I am pretty sure that information is obtainable. That would send a clear signal and show some sign of actual concern with the quality of  the site wrong with the site.

Comment: Ain't gonna happen.

Comment: The user both down voted the question AND ALSO did not understand java. There is nothing wrong with the question. Those are facts. What are we to make of that set of facts. It is perfectly right that I or anyone else should call such "answerers" out for  their behavior. If I did that, I should be called out. If someone asks about nuclear fission and I misunderstand the question and down vote it it is I who am in the wrong and  it is well within the rights of the OP, in fact some would say it  even a duty for the site to remain high quality, to call me out for acting inappropriately.

Comment: Louis -yep. And that's where these problems come from.  Trolls supervising trolls.

Comment: My "Ain't gonna happen" comment has nothing to do with trolls. There are scripts on SE sites that detect voting patterns act to reverse detected abuses (e.g. Alice has a dispute with Bob and she goes to downvote 50 answers of his.) Algorithms perform this work and look at voting *patterns* in the *aggregate*. The day some lofty authority at SE start examining each and every vote to see whether it was a warranted downvote or upvote is the day SE dies.

Comment: If I get you right, you've made a request on meta to allow users to hide their reputation, additionally made on most likely wrong assumptions that the cold shower on Programmers has anything to do with your reputation. People downvote here either because they don't support hiding reputation or because they disagree you were downvoted because of reputation. This is how meta works. How Programmers work, I'm still not sure.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ To be fair, you *will* get downvotes on meta for posting unconstructively and insulting people, even if people don't really disagree with your proposal.  Of course, when both things happen you get that many more downvotes.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ `How Programmers work, I'm still not sure.`  Yeah, we're working that out too.  ;-)

Comment: I see exactly zero "trolls" in the comments here. Everyone is trying to help you, volunteering their free time, and your attitude isn't exactly encouraging us.

Answer (score 23):

Welcome to <del>Programmers</del> Stack Overflow.  For future reference, you should ask questions about a site on their own meta site.  MSO (here) is primarily for questions about issues on SO and questions about issues impacting all of StackExchange.  [Meta Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com) is a lot quieter than here, but you'll still get the Programmers community's attention.

Let's talk about your question.

It started out decent enough, and honestly might be a very good question with a little bit more work behind it.

gnat asked you for clarification , to which you responded.  You explained a bit more of the background that you were looking for.

Somewhere in there, you picked up a downvote, gnat provided an answer, and a flurry of various comments (now deleted) were made.  This is where the problems occurred.  Let's try and address some of them.

1. You made assumptions about who cast votes on your question.  Bad assumption.  Voting is anonymous by design.  And not that you'd necessarily know, but it's highly unlikely gnat downvoted your question.  A) He's generally out of votes by this time of day and B) he doesn't answer questions he downvoted.  There's no way you could have known A but you could have surmised about B.
2. You assumed (gnat's) terse comments were antagonistic.  Not everyone who frequents SE speaks English as their native tongue.  In fact, there are quite a few ESL speakers who are fluent enough that they'll fool many native speakers.  The comments were there to help make your question more constructive and answerable as explained by gnat in one of his comments.
3. You assumed gnat didn't know anything about Java VMs.  Have a look at [gnat's SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat) and the [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-me/topusers)  of the [java-me](/questions/tagged/java-me).  I'm willing to bet he knows something about the subject.
4. You misread his answer.  In short, he said "There's no portable way to do what you're asking."  Instead of clarifying that you don't care about portability, you attacked his answer in the comments and accused gnat of trying to save face.  He wasn't trying to save face, he was genuinely trying to answer your question.

There was possibly a chance of saving your question and cleaning out the comments except that you opened up this MSO rant.  Rants like this on MSO tend not to fare well (hence the current -18 vote).  As a protip, rants on Meta.Programmers still get downvoted, but not as heavily.  Regardless, opening up this post invited more downvotes to your original question, and that's where your question was sunk.

---

You're correct in that a heavily downvoted question is unlikely to see additional answers.  Most of the experts in the community see heavy downvoting as a signal that the question is poorly formed.  It's not worth their time.

But your commentary also guaranteed that no further answers would arrive.  Again, the community members will look over the post and see it's derailed and will just move on to the next one.

---

So what could be done differently?  Obviously, you won't make the same assumptions as you previously did.  You would have done your question wonders if you had edited the positive aspects of your comments back into your question.  Namely, how you defined "native threads" and the fact you didn't care about portability.  Finally, if some time had passed and you didn't think your question was getting an appropriate level of views then you could have asked in Meta.Programmers about how to make the question more constructive and attract more answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate your thoughrfulness. Please note that I said "if you were the one who downvoted my question" in my communication with gnat. I knew I didn't  know with certainity . I specifically disagree that gnat understands the question; his answer directly indicates he doesn't. More, he admitted as much. I see his second post just as I described above. If downvoting is anonymous,, even to admins, that that might be a mistake since who downvotes what is just what information is needed to id abuse.

Comment: @user125027: From your question: "Someone casually and apparently from their own ignorance downgraded it. I corrected them y linking them to the documentation explaining the point they were confused on." That sounds to me like you assumed it was gnat who downvoted your question. Doesn't it read that way to you? And later on in comments: "The user both down voted the question AND ALSO did not understand java."

Comment: Downvoting is anonymous to everyone, including moderators.  SE employees with database access (which is **not** all of them) can perform queries to find the information.  However, that is only done in extreme circumstances.  I understand your feelings on this but this wouldn't qualify as extreme.

Comment: I can walk away, and am going to, but someone somewhere pays the ISP bills that come due each month. They have to have a concern that reasonable users with reasonable questions are being  driven away by , and let's be frank here- adolescent males with nothing to do but uselessly troll this site and accumulate "power" of this and that kind. I heartily recommend Googling "SO sucks" once ina while as I did after posting my question. What you'll find is what I experienced as if this site and those had coordinated my reception. That's when you can be sure- you really have a problem. Best wishes.

Comment: FWIW i managed capture the Op and the response which I will attempt to publicly meditate on in a future blog. I think it's an excellent example what's  wrong with SO and perhaps readers will have some insight intohow SO can be fixed.

Comment: @user125027 For the record, you weren't posting on SO, you were posting on programmers.  If you would like to create your own site where people are only allowed to downvote posts that you think are bad, I welcome you and wish you the best of luck.  SO has no shortage of competition already, and it's been doing well so far on its current model.

Comment: Yeah and every single one of these posts is either ad hominenm or factually wrong. Sergy, what's wrongwith my post? Because according to you there are LOTS of things wrong with it. Except, not in reality. This is what passes for comments nad "halp". Sergy, did I say i wanted to start my own site? Did I say I want to judge all posts to my criteria ? If not, then is your suggestion trolling me? No? Its constructive, like Red Orbits? It is?

Comment: The facts are simply this. I came with a well constructed - in fact-  cogent question. This earned me a down vote by *someone* (and many more now, but people on PE don't vote their feelings because, as I've  been warned by a long time denizen of PE   THAT would be wrong, and lead to banning... ) who , in reality, didn't even know the basics of the question, by his own admission. Complaining about same  earned helpful and constructive advice like "suck it up". This is what happens to people who come to PE with perfectly legit questions  This is the tale of the tape.

Comment: @user125027: No, what's galling is someone being rude repeatedly, and to just about everyone. You talked earlier about "reasonable users" - I don't view your behaviour as reasonable. I can understand how you felt annoyed at the original downvote - but there's no excuse for your rudeness both in that question and this one. As has been suggested elsewhere in this thread, I strongly suggest that you walk away at this point, cool down, and come back when you're less likely to explode at anyone who disagrees with you.

Comment: Yeah but who cares that John Skeet comes on and makes as his sole contribution his personal evaluation of my posts? What is that about except for some reason  you think that's relevant to the question I asked either in this post or my original post, or you think it's smehow important that you say you think I'm rude. It's pretty much 100% OT. I objected to something specific- a fatuous down vote ona  question and the mechanics of the site which permitted it to happen. Your input is pretty much the definition of trolling . Nothing constructive, nothing on point, just your opinion on.. me.

Comment: The thread is just a series of attacks my *attitude* with little or nothing said about the my point. That and a paper thin defence of the answerer's answer, which was and still is problematic inexactly the way I described.Hey John, do everyone who has to interact with you a favor and just leave off trolling threads for which you have no contribution. I don't care how many people in a defective subculture don't like told they're in a defective subculture. That's pretty much what the prefix "meta" means-to frankly discuss as subject what is usually ground. Offended? And?? AND?

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments.

Comment: user125027 makes some excellent points. You should try to understand what he's saying because he's telling you how to make your site better and more useful and clearer for those who are looking for answers to complicated questions that they often don't know how to frame.

Comment: Long story short - downvoting new users' questions (public humiliation) - instead of patient advice as to how to make questions better is a terrible model for a website that offers programming guidance. You're dealing with some powerful emotions here. You're making lifelong enemies when you could be making lifelong friends.

Comment: @Banjobum: I agree that downvoting without an explanation (and if no-one else has added an explanation) isn't productive. But don't you also think that user125027 could learn something here about how to react proportionally rather than going off the handle? I don't personally think the Programmers question is worth a downvote (although I don't think it's as good or clear as the OP thinks either) - but user125027's reaction has been *far* more counter-productive than the downvotes themselves. If this is how they're going to behave at the slightest provocation, I don't think it's much of a loss.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I agree with your assessment of user125027's over-reaction.  I find it highly ironic that this MSO request was in part justified by not being able to attract additional expert answers.  But the OP's reaction here continues to attack and drive away those same experts who could have provided the answer that was being sought.  As much as user125027 is accusing the community of trolling, I believe the converse is the reality.

Comment: It's also the case that being asked a question by another male publicly is a status / ego boost. I believe the way the site is structured attracts some who use it to compensate for their own lack of status security. OTOH there are many very good people here who provide helpful answers and are doing it for altruistic reasons. I'd just try to set things up so it is not so darn easy (and inviting for some) to put a newbie down publicly.

Comment: @Banjobum: So are you suggesting we should just put up with bad questions? You seem to be removing all responsibility from users to ask good questions - there's a *lot* of advice available on doing so. Furthermore, even if someone *is* taken to task for asking a bad question, there is absolutely no excuse to behave as badly as user125027 has. Do you really see absolutely nothing wrong with their behaviour? You only seem to have praise for them. (Also, you seem to be *assuming* that user125027 is male - I haven't seen evidence of that yet, so I'm trying to stay gender-neutral.)

Comment: I wish I had more room in comments to respond. I guess I'm saying that the psychological dynamics of males publicly seeking guidance from other males is a minefield for deep resentments and animosity depending on how it is structured. You have control of that structure. You should expect that newbies esp. will be defensive when asking questions. Your site could more make it appear that responders are wise sages with infinite patience for 'grasshopper'. There will always be the ability to ban someone who is truly a jerk. You ask good questions Jon Skeet.

Comment: @Banjobum: If it's such a minefield, why do *so* many people manage it easily? Just because some people can't be bothered to write good questions, or massively over-react at the slightest criticism, doesn't mean we need to bend the world to suit them. Look at the first few comments on this question - they seem pretty calm to me.

Comment: BTW - I have still not found a 'page' for how to ask questions. I looked. I have seen the topic discussed a lot. Often in the frame of people either asking questions the way you want them to or else leaving. 'How to ask a question' advice should focus on making it more likely you will get a good answer. Also, in many cases a newbie (like me) will be asking the wrong question because of some fundamental misconception I have. The answer is often not where I was looking. By providing a premium in response speed responders are not likely to try to understand the questioners' real problem.

Comment: Continuing from 'By providing a premium in response speed responders are not likely to try to understand the questioners' real problem - and so they will become angry at the questioner when he or she points out that the answer was not helpful. Understanding the question is far more important than providing a fast answer to the wrong question. But it's not nearly as easy to do.

Comment: @Banjobum: When you first ask a question, the site takes you through hints and tips which you have to agree you understand before you ask anything. Then on the "Ask a question" page, there's a box on the right, linking to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. You still seem to be trying to excuse bad questions which people just haven't put time into. It's not about being a beginner - it's about the questioner thinking about it carefully before posting. If I ask a question, it often takes half an hour or more before I'm satisfied with it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I did read those before my 1st question several months ago. I was just downvoted for a question that I spent 2 hrs trying to compose. That was after 2 weeks of trying to research the solution myself. That was after I then went back and added the changes I made to the code in the question as the result of the good advice I received - just in case the fully corrected function might be useful for someone else who had a similar problem. There was zero explanation for the downvote and no place to go to find out what I had done wrong.

Comment: @Banjobum: Well I wouldn't have downvoted that question, although it's not brilliant either. Ultimately a single drive-by downvote really shouldn't be a problem though. Fortunately, *you* didn't decide to go on a rampage, accusing people of being ignorant, or trolls etc. Unlike the OP of *this* question. That's the point. You're not going to manage to get every single user to behave brilliantly - and requiring a comment on downvotes is something that's been discussed to death - but there's just no excuse for the OP's over-the-top reaction here.

Comment: Well, to be honest Jon it did pretty much wreck my day and left a bitter taste on my mouth. That's my point. Don't get me wrong. I think this site is amazing and I appreciate it. I just wish I could use it without having to feel somewhat humiliated every time.

Comment: PS - I'm not trying to ask brilliant questions. I am trying to get past a barrier of lack of knowledge on my part. I'm pretty much admitting I'm not a brilliant guy by asking the question to start with. It is humiliating to then by admonished publicly because someone didn't like the question for whatever mysterious reason. I don't think my reaction is out of the ordinary. How and if you want to deal with it is up to you, of course.

Comment: @Banjobum: If a single downvote from some random person on the internet is enough to put a crimp on your day, I think it's worth re-evaluating what's actually important to you. My point about a "brilliant question" isn't that you need to be brilliant - quite the opposite. You don't need to know the answer in order to ask a good question. If you haven't read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints, that's my own set of hints about how to write a good question. But all of this seems rather a long way from the topic of this question - which is the OP basically going postal for no good reason.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I'm not trying to defend that person or assign blame. I just don't think analyzing the words of very pissed of people will reveal much about the problem. I know a lot of dedicated people (including you I'm guessing) have put a lot of work into this amazing resource for people like me. I'm just gently suggesting that there may be ways to structure your site to minimize that kind of kerfuffle and make it more likely that users - both questioners and responders - will leave believing they had a positive experience.

Comment: @Banjobum: Well, if you have *specific* suggestions, I would ask you to look through Meta Stack Overflow to see if they've already been made - and if not, suggest them here as a new question. (Don't be afraid of downvotes on Meta, by the way - they just mean people disagree with the suggestion; they're not the same as on SO.) The "people are mean to newcomers" complaint is not a new one, but typically the examples given involve poor questions or (as in this case) bad behaviour on the part of the newcomer, for which I have little sympathy.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, As far as evaluating what is important to me, I've made a personal commitment to re-teaching myself a skill that I had several years ago. It's not nearly as easy as it was back then because my brain is not as fast. But in however many years I have left I really want to do this. I'm putting in 50 and 60 hour weeks to that end. And so I do take it seriously when someone tells me I just don't have what it takes and should stop bothering them with stupid questions - which is the message I often get here.

Comment: @Banjobum: Is that the "message you often get" or the message you read into someone leaving a single downvote? There's a significant difference. If users are being rude to you, flag those comments for moderator attention.

Comment: @Jon, Thanks for letting me put in my two cents. But I really need to get back to my project. I've got a mySQL database that runs on my localhost but won't run on my public host. There's always something broke it seems. I'll be coming back to SO looking for answers as usual. Later

Comment: _gnat's ignorance_ strikes again! ["what do method javadocs say?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/238306/shouldnt-androids-textview-gettext-return-string-instead-of-possibly-mutable/238344#comment478363_238306 "comment") -> [answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/238344/31260). There must be something wrong with that gnat guy :)

Answer (score 5):

### Not a good idea

First of all, there's no proof that new users are more likely to be downvoted because they have little reputation. Yes, they **are** downvoted more often, but it's just because they aren't acquainted with SE rules and the culture of given site. If you don't learn to write in a way a given community will understand, you risk being downvoted. Programmers, in my personal opinion, is a hard one. I still have problems figuring out how to ask/answer there.

Second, who would hide their reputation? A new users, of course. So hiding your reputation you would not hide the fact of being a new user. What's worse, people could be more suspicious of why you are you hiding your reputation, and if they take the OP's profile into consideration at all by voting, it could make your situation worse, not better.

Third, even if you hide your reputation, you won't hide the downvotes on the questions or answers in your profile. Hiding vote count on the questions is an absolute no-go, because this is the way we measure quality on our site.

Comment: -1 for actually addressing the OP's feature request.  See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227123/forced-revealing-of-reputation-for-new-users/227128#comment743994_227128  :-D

Comment: @GlenH7 Your link is a little bit off; pretty sure you meant to link [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227123/allow-new-users-to-hide-their-reputation/227128#comment743994_227128)

Comment: @Servy - d'oh.  :-(